# Can caffeinated shampoo have a noticeable effect?

Tags: caffeine

I recently picked up some new shampoo and didn't notice that it included caffeine. I'm curious if this is just a marketing gimmick. Does having a small concentration of caffeine on my scalp for 30-60 seconds actually have a chance of being absorbed?

I'm [fairly sensitive](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/65/why-do-i-feel-shaky-after-only-a-small-amount-of-caffeine) to caffeine, and I *think* I can feel it, but it could easily be the placebo effect.

Comment: By "feel it" do you mean like what happens when you drink coffee?

Comment: @michaelpri Yes, but not quite as strong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a study [described at nih.gov](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3243011/) about the rate of absorption of caffeine through the skin and how hair follicles contribute to it ("significantly", is apparently the answer to that).  Another study compared [how three different substances, including caffeine traveled through different thicknesses of skin in humans and animals](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/8571074_In_vitro_predictions_of_skin_absorption_of_caffeine_testosterone_and_benzoic_acid_a_multi-centre_comparison_study)

The first-referenced article above has this summary about what was known at the beginning of the study:

> Recently, it has been shown that the hair follicles are responsible
>   for a fast delivery of topically applied substances. After topical
>   application, caffeine was already detected in the blood of the
>   volunteers after 5 min, whereas, when the hair follicles were
>   selectively blocked utilizing the newly developed Follicular Closing
>   Technique (FCT), caffeine was detectable only after 20 min

Faith Williams, a researcher who studies skin's permeability to chemicals, had this to say about caffeinated soap in [a 2003 article for the Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/science/2003/nov/27/thisweekssciencequestions1):

> Caffeine does go through the skin if you apply it to the surface in
>   solution But I would have
>   thought that not much would go through [from soap] because I don't
>   think it would stay in contact for very long.

Given that statement, you might experiment on yourself (after getting all the requisite sign-offs that you're complying with [human subject research ethics](http://www.who.int/ethics/research/en/) of course) by leaving the shampoo on your scalp for a longer time before rinsing.