# Can caffeine be absorbed through the skin? Specifically, do caffeinated soaps boost energy?

Tags: caffeine, energy, bath, soap, absorption-absorb

I had no idea that caffeinated soap existed! (You really do learn something new everyday)! So apparently these caffeinated soaps are on the market, but **are they *really* all that effective in boosting energy?**  How does the energy boost compare to consuming a caffeinated soda?

If so, **does that mean that caffeine can be absorbed through the skin?**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can caffeinated shampoo have a noticeable effect?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/523/can-caffeinated-shampoo-have-a-noticeable-effect)